# How to read table from HTML using R

Tags: html, r

I'm trying to read a table that will update every month, and I've searched around but was not able to fix it, please help, thanks!

```
library(XML)
MEItable <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/enso/mei/table.html") 
pre <- MEItable$children$html
pre <- unlist(pre[["body"]][names(body[["body"]]) == "pre"])
```

Comment: Yes I did, and got an empty table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't really need `XML` to read that web page.  In fact, it would be easier to use `read.table` with a few arguments.  This might also be faster since there isn't any xml/html document content being processed.

```
> URL <- "http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/enso/mei/table.html"
> rt <- read.table(URL, skip = 12L, nrow = 65L, fill = TRUE, header = TRUE)
> head(rt, 3)[1:8]
#   YEAR DECJAN JANFEB FEBMAR MARAPR APRMAY MAYJUN JUNJUL
# 1 1950 -1.018 -1.143 -1.290 -1.061 -1.416 -1.372 -1.332
# 2 1951 -1.069 -1.193 -1.208 -0.439 -0.305  0.438  0.715
# 3 1952  0.408  0.135  0.086  0.257 -0.289 -0.657 -0.255
```